# Hide a component on React Native on pressing Back button

Tags: react-native

I am trying to hide a child component on pressing the hardware back key.

This is what I have done so far:

```
render(){

     return(
            <View > 
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.onTypePress('cuisine')}> 
                 <Text>Cuisines</Text> 
               </TouchableOpacity>
               {this.renderFilterType()}    
            </View>
           );
     }

     renderFilterType(){
        if(this.props.showFilterByType){
          return <FilterByType />
        }
     }
```

**this.props.showFilterByType** is a boolean value which I am setting via Redux.

**onTypePress** will trigger the state in Redux state.

I'm handing the back button Press in `FilterByType` like this :

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
     this.handleBackButtonClick= this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this)
}
handleBackButtonClick(){
       this.props.hideFilterByType(' ')
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
      }
componentDidMount(){
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', 
      this.handleBackButtonClick);
    }
```

When I click on Back Button, it goes back to the previous button, but after a second it also closes the application (first screen).

And when I remove `BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);` from FilterByType.js , Back Button stops working throughout the App.

Any suggestion where I am doing wrong, please??!!

Comment: Are the back button event listeners only on your child components?

Comment: yes! only on my child comps @JRK

Comment: So, on your second click (when your child component has unmounted) you have no back button listeners? I'm assuming you dont want to exit the app?

Comment: Yes! Btw I was able to solve it. Check my answer, if it satisfies. @JRK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [React-native BackHandler Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler.html) :

> Android: Detect hardware back button presses, and programmatically invoke the default back button functionality to exit the app if there are no listeners or **if none of the listeners return true**.

Therefore I edited **handleBackButtonClick()** to this :

```
 handleBackButtonClick(){
   this.props.hideFilterByType(' ')
   BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.handleBackButtonClick);
   return true
 }
```